# Datatable sorting incorrect for php datetime am or pm

Tags: javascript, php, html, codeigniter

i want to sort datatable having createddate in am and pm.i am using php codeigniter.sorting is incorrect in ascending and descending.any solution for this?

Below is screenshot

[image]

Below is my code

```
$('.data_Table').DataTable({
    language: {
        paginate: {
            next: '&#8594;', // or '→'
            previous: '&#8592;' // or '←' 
        }
    },  
    "bPaginate": false,
    "bSortable": false,
    "bLengthChange": false,
    "bFilter": false,
    "bInfo": false,
    "bAutoWidth": true
});
```

Comment: Because the date is in the dd-mm-YY format, try change the date in the YYYY-mm-dd format.

Comment: I have used Y-m-d h:i:s a,still sorting is not correct for ascending order

Comment: Friends any solution??

Comment: Have you try to define the type for the date column: columnDefs: [{ targets: [<date column number>], type: 'date'}]. Please take a look here: https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/41826/date-with-time-and-am-pm-is-not-filtering-correctly